# How do I publish a package to GitHub Package Repository?

Tags: maven, github, npm, rubygems, nuget

GitHub introduced its [Package Registry](https://github.blog/2019-05-10-introducing-github-package-registry/). It says:

> It supports familiar package management tools: JavaScript (npm), Java (Maven), Ruby (RubyGems), .NET (NuGet), and Docker images.

But I couldn't find any documentation or example on how to publish a new package there. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will likely need to [sign up for the beta](https://github.com/features/package-registry) first. Their docs have commands in various languages - note that [GitHub Package Registry](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-github-package-registry) should use the language-native tools to push the package to a separate registry.

Here are some examples from https://github.com/features/package-registry.

**npm**

```
npm login --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com --scope=@phanatic
npm publish
```

**RubyGems**

```sh
echo ":github: Bearer ${GH_TOKEN}" >> ~/.gem/credentials
gem build github_api.gemspec
gem push --key github --host https://rubygems.pkg.github.com/phanatic/github_api github_api-1.0.0.gem
```

**Maven**

```
mvn deploy -Dregistry=https://maven.pkg.github.com/phanatic -Dtoken=$GH_TOKEN
```

**NuGet**

```sh
nuget source Add -Name "GitHub" -Source "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/phanatic/octokit/index.json" -UserName phanatic
nuget pack
nuget push "octokit.net.1.0.0.nupkg" -Source "GitHub"
```